# How do I add Preempt RT patch to raspberry pi?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, preempt-rt

I am working on a project that requires Preempt RT patch to Raspberry Pi.

How do I go about adding the latest patch to the latest kernel source?

I have referred to a few websites / tutorials, however they either seem to be broken on outdated.

Answer (score 2):

About installing rtirq: try

```
apt-cache search rtirq
```

And if my memory serves me correctly, the installation is just:

```
apt-get install rtirq
```

Then head over to `/etc/defaults/rtirq`

or something similar (I'm not at a linux computer right now) and change the settings...

Finally, run

```
systemctl enable rtirq
systemctl start rtirq
```

and you should be set.

Comment: Hey @Mohtashim,
Can you elaborate on the steps involving modification of rtirq? I am a beginner in this. 

Also, what is the difference between on rtirq and preempt rt?